# Prevent window of PDF from asking for Password

Tags: html, pdf

I've been given access to the CMS of a website. I uploaded a password protected PDF file.  Then I made an `<a>` link to the pdf file.  When I click on the link, I get taken to the url of the PDF file, and then a pop up prompts me for password.  I do not know the password, so I press cancel.  A split second later, the pop up comes back again asking for password.  I press cancel again, only to have the pop up comes back. This happens indefinitely.  The only way to exit this page is to open up my task manager and kill the browser.

Is there a way to get around this problem?  Things I can not do are:

a) I do not have server access.  I only have access to a WYSIWYG editor

b) I do not have the password to the PDFs, nor am I allowed to remove the password protection on the PDFs

Comment: So basically, you cannot do anything and want to prevent the annoying, not well thought out behavior of *one specific PDF viewer* (because I don't think *all* PDF viewers act this way)? Sounds like you're in a bad position...

Comment: This is not possible without server access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your PDF file on another external server where you do have server access.  Then have your CMS point to that file on the external server.

Then on your external server make a change to your .htaccess, i.e. to force the pdf to download:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
AddType application/octet-stream .doc
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mpg
AddType application/octet-stream .mov
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Comment: I changed your answer a little bit based on what Al told me